# Plot discrete values using geom tile and scale_gradient_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following part of a data frame which is much bigger than this:

```
    x   y       A    
    1   1  0.1176405
    2   2  0.1176405
    3   3  0.1219375
    4   4 0.09942536
    5   5  0.1031696
    6   6  0.1384145
```

And I'm trying to plot using ggplot2:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=A))+ 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "red")
```

But I always get this error:

```
Error: Non-continuous variable supplied to scale_fill_gradient.
```

When I try `as.numeric(A)` in the plot it does work but the values in the plot looks weird and does not present my values.

that's the output of `str()`:

```
'data.frame':   289 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: num  1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ y: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ A: Factor w/ 181 levels "0.1176405","0.1219375",..: 1 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 ...
```

So what should I do to make this plot work?

Comment: Can you show the output from `str()` on your data?

Comment: @joran: i add it to the question

Comment: Can you show us what you get?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: i don't get a result, just the error found in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `A` in your data frame is a factor and needs to be converted to numeric. Try:

```
df$A <- as.numeric(as.character(df$A))
```

and then run your code.

Casting factors to numeric with `as.numeric` without converting to character first is a common gotcha:

```
as.numeric(factor(50:55))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

See [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) 8.2.1